# Как запустить Spice Proxmox на убунту?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxmox

Я пытаюсь сделать Spice для виртуальной машины. Настройки ВМ я установил, а что дальше делать - не знаю. В интернете не понимаю. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Я скачивал и папку `spice-vdagent-0.21.0` и `pve-spice.vv`

Также `sudo apt-get install spice-vdagent`

Comment: А `guest-tools` поставил?

Comment: Клиент спайс в проксмокс добавили уже?